# Water heater refuses to light after power outage

Tags: water-heater

I have an AO Smith FPSH 40 252 High-Efficiency gas water heater, about 14 years old. Today we had a power outage due to high winds and when the power came back on, the heater refuses to ignite. The blower comes on, the igniter starts to glow but never sparks - it shuts off with a click about a second after the gas comes on.  It repeats this three times and shuts down.  The green indicator light blinks six times, then pauses, which according to [this](http://waterheatertimer.org/pdf/Honeywell-Gas-Valve-LED-Codes-2000.pdf) indicates "System in lockout/Unit failed to light".

I have tried sanding the flame sensor and the perforated sheath covering the glowing element, as well as cleaning the rust off the little disc where the gas comes out. I have also tried "jiggling the harnesses" as one helpful forum user posted.

The gas is working fine. There are no obstructions in the vent pipe.

I should also note that I asked [this possibly-related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29070/what-could-be-causing-corrosion-on-a-water-heater-burner) about the same unit about a year and a half ago, so that might provide some additional background. The unit has been working fine, with cleaning of the disc and flame sensor about twice a year, up until today.

Do I need a new igniter assembly? Could today's blackout have caused the problem I am seeing? We had no blown breakers.

I really don't want to start purchasing parts without a clear understanding of the problem. Is there anything else I can try?

[image: igniter]

[image: green light blinks six times]

Comment: Can you light the burner with a long match or grill lighter?

Comment: ahh, that thought had occurred to me but it's not really in my comfort zone to do something like that with a gas appliance. It turns out I had some carbon build up on the igniter element (the part inside that perforated sheath that I had not cleaned out last night) and I'm back in business now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a family friend who's a professional come out and he cleaned off the igniter a little more thouroughly than I had, and that solved the issue. A happy ending!